# Rails double render error despite using if then statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise

I frequently use both `render` and `redirect_to` but combining in an `if...then` statement so that the action by default only has 1. Not sure why this is not working in this case with Devise.

What I need to do is whether a user is confirmed or not, immediately after s/he signs up successfully I need to POST to another controller to create some other things, which is why the redirect_to is the same. But I'm getting the `DoubleRender` error

Thanks!

For your reference, this is the Devise code:

```
# POST /resource
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

Then my code:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to "/plan_date_create"
end

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to "/plan_date_create"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `respond_with`s do a render and then `after_sign_up_path_for` and `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` do redirects, and you're calling both `respond_with` and one or the other of those methods on the same line of code.